# Definition of dual basis using gradient

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

I am trying to read up on tensor calculus, but am stuck at a definition I find unintuitive.

[image]

I understand the normal basis definition with partial derivative, and can visualize what it represents ("as the component increases, which direction does the vector move towards"). But I can't visualize the dual basis. Can anyone offer any useful resources for understanding this? I could not find any online. I believe I understand dual basis for covectors, but I do not see the relation between covectors and gradient operators.

Progress so far: Is this video related? https://youtu.be/XGL-vpk-8dU It talks about how differential forms are covectors

Comment: This question seems a bit too broad to be answered concisely in a SE post. As far as visualizations of the dual-vectors (1-forms) go, the only resource I can recall that tackled that was Misner-Thorne-Wheeler (in the context of GR). I'm not sure how much that visualization will help you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradients are formed by holding 2 coordinates constant so that a surface is formed; the gradient is then normal to that. In orthogonal systems the two sets can be matched to point in the same direction but the magnitudes are different such that dotting the gradients with the basis gives you a kroenicker delta.